# I can't use someone else's model to generate inputs to mine, in a generator. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a neural network on the SQuAD v1.1 dataset, using a pretrained BERT model. Someone suggested that I first grab the output of the BERT model and then feed those into my neural network as inputs. Due to the large amount of data, I feel that I need to create a generator, on which my neural network can then fit:

```
# @title Preparation
!pip install -q keras-bert
!wget -q https://storage.googleapis.com/bert_models/2018_10_18/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12.zip
!unzip -o uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12.zip
```

```
import os
```

```
pretrained_path = 'uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12'
config_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'bert_config.json')
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'bert_model.ckpt')
vocab_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'vocab.txt')
```

```
# TF_KERAS must be added to environment variables in order to use TPU
os.environ['TF_KERAS'] = '1'
import codecs
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
```

```
token_dict = {}
with codecs.open(vocab_path, 'r', 'utf8') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        token = line.strip()
        token_dict[token] = len(token_dict)
```

```
model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path)
import numpy as np
from keras_bert import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(token_dict)
def tokenize(text):
  tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  indices, segments = tokenizer.encode(first=text, max_len=512)
  return indices,segments
def feature_extraction(texts):
  return_values = []
  for text_ in texts:
    try:
      text_.split(" ")
    except AttributeError as e:
      raise TypeError("Expected array of strings.")
    try:
      indices,segments = tokenize(text_)
      predicts = model.predict([np.array([indices] * 8), np.array([segments] * 8)])[0]
      return_values.append(predicts)
    except ValueError as v:
      print(v)
  return_values = np.array(return_values)
  return return_values
print(feature_extraction(text_array).shape)
def batch_generator(dataframe,batch_size):
  while True:
    batch = dataframe.sample(n=batch_size)
    try:
      batch_features = feature_extraction(batch["question"].values)
    except ValueError as v:
      print("Oops, I'm getting a ValueError for batch_features.")
      print(v)
    try:
      batch_targets = batch["answer_start"]
    except ValueError as v:
      print("Oops, I'm getting a ValueError for batch_targets.")
      print(v)

    yield batch_features,batch_targets
```

This works when I feed it test data:

```
def batch_generator(dataframe,batch_size):
  while True:
    batch = dataframe.sample(n=batch_size)
    try:
      batch_features = feature_extraction(batch["question"].values)
    except ValueError as v:
      print("Oops, I'm getting a ValueError for batch_features.")
      print(v)
    try:
      batch_targets = batch["answer_start"]
    except ValueError as v:
      print("Oops, I'm getting a ValueError for batch_targets.")
      print(v)

    yield batch_features,batch_targets
```

This works when I use this test code:

```
testDataframe = pd.DataFrame({"question":["Does she sell seashells by the seashore?"],"answer":["She sells seashells by the seashore"],"answer_start":[0]})
for x,y in batch_generator(testDataframe,1):
  print (x)
  print (y)
  break
```

**Output:**

> [[[-0.11251544 -0.09277309  0.04996187 ... -0.43535435  0.23852573
>       0.3206718 ]   [ 0.35688528  0.43881682 -0.1390086  ... -0.32458037  0.64422214    -0.11743623]   [ 0.6213926  -0.9945548   0.07564903 ... -0.87357795  0.2069801    -0.25303575]   ...   [-0.06796454 -0.24819699 -0.25508618 ...  0.20477912  0.36703664
>       0.04691853]   [ 0.15030818 -0.05989693  0.17198643 ...  0.19960165  0.0324061    -0.31075317]   [ 0.05091426 -0.14167279  0.18194658 ...  0.12112649  0.05029908    -0.15253511]]] 0    0 Name: answer_start, dtype: int64

I create and compile my neural network and inputs like so:

```
import json
import re
#regex = re.compile(r'\W+')
import json
import re
#regex = re.compile(r'\W+')
def readFile(filename):
  with open(filename) as file:
    fields = []
    JSON = json.loads(file.read())
    articles = []
    for article in JSON["data"]:
      articleTitle = article["title"]
      article_body = []
      for paragraph in article["paragraphs"]:
        paragraphContext = paragraph["context"]
        article_body.append(paragraphContext)
        for qas in paragraph["qas"]:
          question = qas["question"]
          answer = qas["answers"][0]
          fields.append({"question":question,"answer_text":answer["text"],"answer_start":answer["answer_start"],"paragraph_context":paragraphContext,"article_title":articleTitle})
      article_body = "\\n".join(article_body)
      article = {"title":articleTitle,"body":article_body}
      articles.append(article)
  fields = pd.DataFrame(fields)
  #fields["question"] = fields["question"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["question"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  #fields["paragraph_context"] = fields["paragraph_context"].str.replace(regex," ")
  #fields["answer_text"] = fields["answer_text"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["paragraph_context"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["article_title"] = fields["article_title"].str.replace("_"," ")
  assert not (fields["article_title"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  return fields,articles
```

```
trainingData,trainingArticles = readFile("train-v1.1.json")
```

```
answers_network = Sequential()
answers_network.add(Dense(32,input_shape=(512,768)))
answers_network.summary()
answers_network.compile("rmsprop","categorical_crossentropy")
answers_network_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('answers_network-rnn-best.h5', verbose=1, monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
answers_network.fit_generator(batch_generator(trainingData[["question","paragraph_context","answer_start"]],100),steps_per_epoch=8)
```

This fails with an error:

> Tensor Input-Token:0, specified in either feed_devices or
>   fetch_devices was not found in the Graph

Now, Input-Token is the name of one of the input layers in the BERT model.

I think TensorFlow is suggesting that the BERT model is using a different graph than my model.

Apparently, the BERT model uses custom layers and activation functions, so making a deep copy of the model may not be the best course of action.

What should I do?

EDIT: A copy of my train-v1.1.json dataset is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQbrQnH3WkibtXIHFA88gJuGESvyz-Ag/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How can I reproduce the problem? Could you please point me to the download link for `'train-v1.1.json'`?

Comment: @rvinas: Right here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQbrQnH3WkibtXIHFA88gJuGESvyz-Ag/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The script has pandas errors after loading the data. Please make it fully reproducible.

Comment: @rvinas: That's odd. Here, try getting the JSON file from this link: https://github.com/moonman239/Capstone-project/blob/master/data.zip If that doesn't work, I've also eited this question to include the original readFile function (which includes details I had omitted for brevity.)

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

Generate the data first and save it. 
Later you train with the saved data.

It seems like doing this:

```
features = feature_extraction(text_array)
np.save('features.npy', features) #or not...
```

Then just fit with this array later:

```
features = np.load('features.npy')    
new_model.fit(features, targets, ...)
```

---

If the data is too big for your memory (there is no problem with the model, just set a proper `batch_size`. This is also true for the bert model when generating features), I mean, the whole data can't fit your memory, then you could save the batches individually:

```
for i in range(batches):
    batch = text_array[i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size)
    features = feature_extraction(batch)
    np.save('batch' + str(i) + '.npy', features)
```

Your generator then loads these batches:

```
while True:
    for i in range(batches):
        batch = np.load('batch' + str(i) + '.npy')
```

### Option 2

Make the models use the same graph, creating a single big model:

```
bertInputs = Input(shape_for_bert_input)
bertOutputs = bert_model(bertInputs)
yourOutputs = your_model(bertOutputs)

fullModel = Model(bertInputs, yourOutputs)
```

Train using the generator directly from the dataframe, the bert prediction will happen automatically as a part of your model.

---

Alternatively, if you want to see all layers explicitly in the summary:

```
bertOutputs = bert_model.output
yourOutputs = Dense(....)(bertOutputs)

fullModel = Model(bert_model.input, yourOutputs)
```

Comment: So, option #2 looks like the fastest option. What should the bert_model and your_model function definitions look like?

Comment: `bert_model` and `your_model` are keras models, you create them the way you want to.

Comment: Moller: Should I do my tokenizations in the model itself, or in the generator?

Comment: In option 2, in the model itself. Unless the bert model is too big for fitting in the GPU (but remember to set every layer in the bert model as `layer.trainable = false` before compiling your model.